# Do we need to rebuild the link databases on CD Server?

Tags: upgrade, installation, link-database

I cannot find any official documentation on Rebuilding the Link Databases and not sure which DB to select when choosing DB for rebuilding Link Databases.

According to the official installation guild, it says "Select the Master and Core databases and the click Rebuild." but what about Web DB?

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: If you do not actively use the link database in your code, it is not necessary to rebuild the link database in your web db.

Answer (score 2):

No, It is not required to rebuild Link databases in CD environments. Publishing will keep your link database updated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason why you would need to build it in Web. Once you build it in Master a publish should update Web. You can however update and get an item links in code.

For instance:

```
 Globals.LinkDatabase.UpdateReferences(currentItem);
    ItemLink[] links = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetItemReferrers(currentItem, true);
    if (links != null)
    {
      //do something
    }
```